# Indentation on python

Tags: python, modular

My python program isnt running. Im sure im missing something but im pretty sure i just indented wrong. Can anyone lend me a hand? thank you!

```html
def main():
    sales = getSales()
    advancedPay = getAdvancedPay()
    commRate = DetermineCommRate(sales)
    pay = (sales * commRate) - advancedPay
    print("The pay is $". format(pay, ",.2f"), sep="")
    
if pay < 0:
    print("The salesperson must reimburse")
    print("the company")

def getSales():
    monthlySales = float(input("Enter the monthly sales: "))
    return monthlySales

def getAdvancedPay():
    print("Enter the amount of advanced pay or ")
    print("Enter 0 if no advanced pay was given. ")
    advancedPay - float(input("Advanced pay: ")
    return advancedPay
    

def DetermineCommRate
    if sales < 10000:
        rate = 0.10
    elif sales >= 10000 and sales <= 14999.99:
        rate = 0.12
    elif sales >= 15000 and sales <= 17999.99:
        rate = 0.14
    elif sales >= 18000 and sales <= 21999.99:
        rate = 0.16
    else:
        rate = 0.18

    return rate

main()
```

My python program isnt running. Im sure im missing something but im pretty sure i just indented wrong. Can anyone lend me a hand? thank you!

Comment: `advancedPay - float(input("Advanced pay: ")`? Replace`-` with `=` and add a closing parens

Comment: The other problem you have is `def DetermineCommRate` is not written properly, you forgot your closing parentheses and colon => `def DetermineCommRate():`

Comment: You  have improper syntax all over the place. Please proofread your code.

Comment: In the future please provide a more complete [mcve] of your code. Also, I suspect that maybe you are not using a proper editor that would have pointed several of these syntax errors for you already.

Comment: thank you guys! both of those help out but now im getting this

Comment: @BottomOut Indent!

Comment: @idjaw yeah our coding classes editor sucks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, `sales` is a local variable in the `main()`, and you are trying to access it in `DetermineCommRate`, and you have syntax errors in the definition of that function

```
def DetermineCommRate(sales):
```

Currently, you are passing sales to it, but not accepting it.

Also, your following line should be indented to run in the main()

```
if pay < 0:
    print("The salesperson must reimburse")
    print("the company")
```

And a syntax error in this line too

```
advancedPay = float(input("Advanced pay: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments; I deleted the invalid stuff and kept working on the program.

You're missing several syntax errors.  You need to close off parentheses in the input of advancedPay, finish the declaration of DetermineCommRate, indent the **if pay** block, and then reconcile that declaration (number & names of params) with the use (one argument).

You also have a formatting problem with the final printing.  Check the examples again and fix the specification to print **pay**.

```
def main():
    sales = getSales()
    advancedPay = getAdvancedPay()
    commRate = DetermineCommRate(sales)
    pay = (sales * commRate) - advancedPay
    print("The pay is $ {0:8.2f}". format(pay), sep="")

    if pay < 0:
        print("The salesperson must reimburse")
        print("the company")

def getSales():
    monthlySales = float(input("Enter the monthly sales: "))
    return monthlySales

def getAdvancedPay():
    print("Enter the amount of advanced pay or ")
    print("Enter 0 if no advanced pay was given. ")
    advancedPay = float(input("Advanced pay: "))
    return advancedPay

def DetermineCommRate(sales):
    if sales < 10000:
        rate = 0.10
    elif sales >= 10000 and sales <= 14999.99:
        rate = 0.12
    elif sales >= 15000 and sales <= 17999.99:
        rate = 0.14
    elif sales >= 18000 and sales <= 21999.99:
        rate = 0.16
    else:
        rate = 0.18

    return rate

main()
```

Comment: im using python 3

Comment: it works but only one problem. when i input all the numbers i get the ouput ::

Comment: "the pay is $ " but i dont get a number after it

Comment: Right.  As I said, check your examples from class and fix the formatting.

Comment: Never mind; I added it to my solution.  You didn't get any output because your formatting string is only **"The pay is $"**.  This has no format specifications.  The ",.2f" later in the line is given as a value to be printed.